# Set font weight bold programatically to true type font - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I've a font name abc.ttf which gives bold in html web if font weight is set to bold but in codenameone, it never gives bold font. How can I achieve that?
The following code doesn't gives the bold font.

```
Font fnt = Font.createTrueTypeFont("abc.ttf", 3).derive(40, Font.STYLE_BOLD);
serviceTypeLabel.getAllStyles().setFont(fnt);
```

In theme how can we set bold font to .ttf file

[image]

Update 1: 
Using bold ttf works fine but only half of the letters are seen. Have a look at the image below. Here service no 12 is only half visible:

[image]

Comment: Where isn't this working? Is the setting saved? Does it work on the simulator, device etc? Looking at the code this should work roughly the same way.

Comment: The problem is that the text is not bold. Font.createTrueTypeFont("abc.ttf", 3).derive(40, Font.STYLE_BOLD); This line has no effect.

Comment: If it doesn't work in the code it won't work in the UI either. Usually TTFs are divided to separate versions for bold/regular etc. You would need the TTF matching bold. That second field is ignored for almost all fonts.

Comment: I used bold ttf file and it works but only half of the letters are seen. What happened? Plz see the update above.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a bold TTF font. When applying the font you need to apply it to all states. If you do it after layout you need to animate the layout or revalidate. Since the bold font has different measurements.

Comment: yeahh I used it in unselected, selected, pressed in theme and set it as UIId of the component. I have used revalidate() at the end of the code as well... But it is not fully shown in devices and simulator too.

Comment: What type of code was used to generate the screenshot you provided? All of those things collide with one another so you need to pick one strategy and make sure it works correctly.

Comment: I'm reopening a question, its messy here. And I found out the issue is odd. Have a look at the specific question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465390/only-half-of-the-letters-of-the-component-are-seen-cn1