# Only half of the letters of the component are seen - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I used bold ttf font and it works but only half of the letters are seen.

**Code:**

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Label testLabel = new Label("Bold Font Not Working");
    testLabel.setUIID("smallBold");

    Form splashForm = new Form(new BorderLayout());
    splashForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, BoxLayout.encloseY(testLabel));
    splashForm.show();

    splashForm.revalidate();
}
```

**UIID in theme for unselected, selected and pressed style**

[image]

**How it looks now**

[image]

However without wrapping it in boxlayout or flowlayout and directly adding it in the form with borderlayout works. P.S if the form is in boxlayout, it doesn't work

**Code:**

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    Label testLabel = new Label("Bold Font Not Working");
    testLabel.setUIID("smallBold");

    Form splashForm = new Form(new BorderLayout());
    splashForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, testLabel);// this works
    splashForm.show();

    splashForm.revalidate();
}
```

Image when the label is not wrapped in other containers

[image]

Comment: The different layout aspects just indicate the component itself is sized differently which you can see in the component inspector. The cutting happens because drawing is outside the preferred size. We'll need a copy of the TTF file in order to reproduce this.

Comment: Here is the ttf font: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_1M4Hnw89x6pQMvZQRhJn0-_4VZqh7Vg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Java was having difficulty reading the height of this font correctly as it has a negative descent.  I have posed a workaround in Git that will be deployed in the next update on Friday.

Comment: Hello @stevehannah it is workable in iOS devices and simulator but it doesn't work in android devices. I checked in samsung j7 prime(android version 7.0). Can I do anything to make it work in android devices?